# Passing parameters with links

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, hyperlink

routes.rb

```
resources :carts do
  resources :cart_items
end
```

rake routes:

```
cart_cart_items   POST   /carts/:cart_id/cart_items(.:format)            cart_items#create
```

When I click on the link, it should create new item in cart_items:

```
     link_to 'Add to Cart', '#'
```

I need help with this link. Also how to pass :cart_id through the link.I'm a newbie to rails. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not enough information - you need to show us the controller code that actually creates the cart_item that you want to reach via the link. A link itself doesn't add anything. Or are you asking for that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `@cart`, then doing `link_to 'Add to Cart', cart_path(@cart)` will suffice.

Comment: That link will just bring him to the `show` page for the cart, not add an item.